# Optimising SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on an SQL Server database which imports files for several accounts and then matches payments to transactions.  Some transactions will never receive a matching payment, so a matching dummy payment needs to be automatically generated.  However, the payments still have to be related to an import, so a dummy import has to be generated first, and of course each account has to be kept separate.  This code works all right but I think it's kind of a brute force method and am concerned that it may be a problem when the database grows very large.  I've never needed to write a query like this from scratch, and I'm also new to SQL Server (I've worked on lots of projects using MySQL and SQLite), so I hope my code doesn't look too crude.  I would appreciate any suggestions for improvement.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT
    AccountID, <several more fields>
    INTO #temp1
    FROM Transactions 
    WHERE <several conditions>

  SELECT AccountID
    INTO #temp2
    FROM #temp1
    GROUP BY AccountID

  DECLARE @anAccountID int
  DECLARE @theImportID int
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp2)
  BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @anAccountID=AccountID FROM #temp2

    INSERT INTO Imports
    (AccountID, <several more fields>) VALUES (@anAccountID, <several more fields>)
    SET @theImportID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Payments
    (ImportID, AccountID, <several more fields>)
    (
      SELECT
      @theImportID,
      AccountID, <several more fields>
      FROM #temp1
      WHERE AccountID=@anAccountID
    )

    DELETE FROM #temp2 WHERE AccountID=@anAccountID
  END

  DROP TABLE #temp2
  DROP TABLE #temp1
COMMIT
```

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Cursors and loops are the slowest way to perform inserts. They also make the query hard to read. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This could be rewritten as a set based solution quite easily using OUTPUT.

Comment: A simple `INSERT ...SELECT` will insert data to `Imports` and `Payments` without a loop. Addint the `OUTPUT` when inserting to `Imports` will return the new IDs. These can be stored in a table variable. Or you could use the `INSERT INTO Imports` query as a subquery that generates the data to insert into `Payments`. Hard to test though without the tables' schema and test data

Answer (score 1):

Using OUTPUT you can greatly simplify this process. There is no need for temp tables or loops to simply insert data. This is a rough sketch of what your code might look like.

```
Insert IMPORTS
(
    AccountID
    , <several more fields>
)
output inserted.ImportID
    , inserted.AccountID
    , inserted.<several more fields>
into Payments
select AccountID
    , <several more fields>
from Transactions
```

You can read more about the OUTPUT clause in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

There are also hundreds and hundreds of articles about this with examples. The hard part is knowing what to look for.